# Password validation with Respect Validation

Tags: php, validation, respect-validation

I've currently got a regular expression set up for validating my passwords:

```
/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W).{6,}$/
```

This checks for at least 1 uppercase and lowercase character, 1 digit, 1 special character/non-word character and minimum of 6 characters.

I'm now porting all of my validation rules over to [Respect Validation](https://respect-validation.readthedocs.io/). I've got most of it set up nicely but having difficulty with password validation.

I'm aware of the `regex` method:

```
Validator::regex('/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W).{6,}$/')->setName('Password');
```

But this returns an error message like this:

```
Password must validate against "/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W).{6,}$/"
```

I'm wanting to chain methods together so each rule is set in the validation chain. So if it's a digit you are missing it returns something like "Password must contain at least 1 digit", if you're missing an uppercase character it returns "Password must contain at least 1 uppercase character" and so on.

I thought it might be done using the [`allOff`](https://respect-validation.readthedocs.io/en/1.1/rules/AllOf/) method, whereby you can set individual rules that will pass globally if all inner rules pass.

As a test, I tried to detect if the string contains a digit and an alpha character like this:

```
Validator::allOf(Validator::digit(), Validator::alpha())->setName('Password');
```

The results:

```
$password = 'test'; // Password must contain only digits (0-9)
$password = '1234'; // Password must contain only letters (a-z)
$password = 'test1234' // Password must contain only digits (0-9)
```

Looking at it now, it makes perfect sense why I got those errors, but I can't see how else to do this without the `regex` method. Is what I'm after possible is it just best to use the `regex` method in this case, I've gone through the rule list a few times but I've probably missed the one I'm after as there is quite a few.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated to [tag:respect-validation], but you might find [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48345922/3600709) useful.